# Autocomplete Field Type?

Tags: custom-fields, fields

Is there a way to have a field with autocomplete values that are based on the input from another field? The values would be a result of previously entered data in the Channels (along with some other custom logic possibly). Is there an addon for this already? Or a native way to do this in EE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Suggest Field](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/suggest-field) fieldtype? It uses previous values entered in the same field (previous entries), but it could be easily modified to look at another field instead.

Comment: be beware that the fieldtype is not dynamically fetching data, it will output ALL data in the page-source for javascript to access. This can be an issue if you have many-many entries.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably going to be to develop your own [Fieldtype](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/fieldtypes.html) add-on. Using [Pkg.io](http://pkg.io/) to generate the boilerplate will kickstart the process for you.

That said, if you want to use an existing add-on then [Playa](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa) could come close to what you need. It has autocomplete when using single-select mode. The multiple-select mode (called drop panes) has match-anywhere filtering using a search input built right into the field. And you have a lot of control over what channel entries are available in the field by pulling entries only from specific channels, statuses, authors, and/or categories.

Update: Even better, see [the answer posted by Derek](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/1501/22) to check out the Suggest Field!